# Reverse CSS changes done my jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

So this is what I'm doing. I have a default set of CSS for each element, but I need to modify it on click.

Is there easy way to reverse the change that is done by jQuery action? Just like rolling back the default set styles? I do this manually, but I would like to do this automatically, somehow without hard coding anything.

jQuery

```
            main.find('li').each(function() {
                var sub1 = $(this);

                if(sub1.has('ul').length > 0) {
                    var bg = sub1.css('background-image');

                    sub1.click(function() {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        event.stopPropagation();

                        if(!sub1.find('> ul').is(':visible')) {
                            sub1.css('border-bottom', '2px solid #E1E000');
                            sub1.css('background-image', 'url(img/square0.png)');
                            sub1.find('> a').css('color', '#D8A2DD');
                        }
                        else {
                            sub1.css('border-bottom', '2px solid transparent');
                            sub1.css('background-image', bg);
                            sub1.find('> a').css('color', '#fff');
                        }

                        sub1.find('> ul').toggle();
                    });
                }
                else {
                    sub1.click(function(event) {
                        event.stopPropagation();
                    });
                }
            });
```

CSS

```
.menu > li > ul > li {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left 0 top 5px;
}

.menu > li > ul > li:nth-child(3n+1) {
    background-image: url(img/square1.png);
}

.menu > li > ul > li:nth-child(3n+2) {
    background-image: url(img/square2.png);
}

.menu > li > ul > li:nth-child(3n+3) {
    background-image: url(img/square3.png);
}
```

Comment: It might be easier to simply add and remove a class on click, and modify your styling as needed.

Comment: I could not get this accomplished for some reason, I'm not sure why, I still would have to have 3 different classes, and I try to avoid coding more classes.

Comment: Adding & removing classes is easy.  Undoing something like "sub1.css('border-bottom', '2px solid transparent');" is not easy, because JS doesn't know what the previous value for 'border-bottom' was, if any.  So the "undo" for that command would be to simply remove 'border-bottom', which is likely not what you want.

Comment: If you find yourself with too many classes on certain element it helps to start nested them so you can do selectors like ".specific-parent .general-child"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use classes to specify css properties. jquery has [addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [removeClass](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) to add/remove classes.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this. I'm just curious if there's other way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

This will remove all the inline styles on an element:

```
$("selector").attr({style : ""});
```

Answer (score 1):

The most manageable way to do this is to add and remove classes as needed.  In the example below, there is a 'default' class and a 'special' class.  The properties of the 'special' class override those of the 'default' class, so all we need to do is control whether or not the element has the 'special' class.

Assume that the element sub1 already has the 'default' class, and let the IF statement decide whether or not it also has the overriding 'special' class.

```
// Assuming sub1 already has class 'default'
if (!sub1.find('> ul').is(':visible')) {
    sub1.addClass('special');
} else {
    sub1.removeClass('special');
}
```

CSS:

```
.default {
    border-bottom: '2px solid #E1E000';
    background-image: 'url(img/square0.png)';
}
.default > a {
    color: #fff;
}
.special {
    border-bottom: '2px solid transparent';
    background-image: 'url(img/square1.png)';
}
.special > a {
    color: #D8A2DD;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always get rid of styles set by Javascript by just using Javascript to set those styles to "".

So whatever styles you want to reset just do

```
$("selector").css({style1: "", style2: ""})
```

Comment: But that doesn't reset them to default, but completely clears them. Right?

Comment: That's the issue with adding & removing styles - there is no "default", there is only a previous value that JS is not aware of, unless you tell it to store the previous value.

Comment: Fun fact: If you set a css value to an empty string with JS it'll defer it to the CSS value for that property. http://jsfiddle.net/34upcbz8/